# Почему Google обожает делать незначительные обновления Android SDK?

Tags: обсуждение

Почему так происходит? Каждый месяц приходится редактировать `Gradle` для того, чтобы среда разработки перестала ругаться на старый SDK, когда вышел новый.

Обновился до `Gradle 3.4.1`, не мог собрать приложение из-за очень странных ошибок, которых раньше не было. Сейчас пришла просьба обновиться до `Gradle 3.4.2`, и ошибка пропала. То же самое с `Support Library`. Да и с версиями `Android`. Что появляется в новых `Android`?

Как пользователь замечу, что с каждым обновлением требуется всё больше ресурсов для нормальной работы, но при этом никаких других изменений заметить невозможно.

Где я ошибаюсь?